# I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Too many open files

Tags: java, jmeter

I am using Apache Jmeter for testing our application but suddenly most of the errors that Jmeter displayed was

```
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:447) at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:510) at java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1101)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSokcetFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:126)
```

as I searched on the internet most of the comments about this error is because of the open limit of the machine, and then there was an answer that said Entities should be consume and when I tried on consuming the Entities the number of errors were reduced but not that many. are there any other ways to handle this kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

Default maximum number of open files and or sockets on Linux machines is 1024.

If your test exceeds it although shouldn't you need to inspect your test and detect and fix leaks.

If it's expected and you just increase limits on files/sockets it should be possible to increase them to reasonably higher value. See `ulimit` command reference and information on `limits.conf` file.Alternatively you could try running JMeter as root user.

To get maximum number of allowed open files execute

```
ulimit -n
```

in terminal

References:

- [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) - guide on JMeter tuning and best practices
- Linux [ulimit](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ulimit.htm) command reference
- [limits.conf](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.files/doc/aixfiles/limits.htm) file documentation

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you create a lot of `Socket`s but do not `.close()` them properly.

You don't show code so no one can fix that for you; anyway, there are classical idioms when dealing with `Socket`s, or indeed *any* class which implements `Closeable` ([which `Socket` does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)).

With Java 6:

```
final Closeable closeable = whatever(); // or Socket, or InputStream, or...
try {
    doSomethingWith(closeable);
} finally {
    closeable.close();
}
```

With Java 7:

```
try (
    final Closeable closeable = whatever();
) {
    doSomethingWith(closeable);
}
// Automatically closed for you
```

NOTE: with Java 7, it is in fact anything which implements `AutoCloseable`; and `Closeable` extends `AutoCloseable`.

NOTE 2: if Java 6 and you can afford Guava 14+, consider using [`Closer`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html).

Comment: sorry I was not allowed to post any part of the working code so I just posted the error message, anyways is it applicable to httpClient?

Comment: Well, if `HttpClient` implements `Closeable`, yes it is

Comment: i tried the closeable and somehow it didn't work, I found a snippet like httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); . is it someway similar to the Closeable?